# Will upgrade to Android 4.3 with Samsung Knox make my s3 impossible to root?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-knox

So my Galaxy s3 has finally offered to upgrade to 4.3.

I've heard Android 4.3 contains Samsung Knox which I have heard is a security feature that will make it impossible or at least really risky / difficult to root.

Is this true? Will I still be able to root my phone after I upgrade to Knox?

If I plan to root my phone after my warranty expires, should I not take this upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

1. Depending on what version of S3 you have (there are [13 just looking at the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III)), there could be different safeguards in place to prevent tamporing
2. Having KNOX installed is one thing, upgrading to 4.3 is another as some of the updates that Samsung has put in prevent certain types of expolots to get the bootloader unlocked and ability to boot a unapproved rom
3. A coworker of mine upgraded his phone to 4.3 and serious issues with KNOX not letting him boot. He had to downgrade all the way back to 4.1 and then upgrade back up to get a working phone. Needless to say, all of his data is lost.
4. If you are planning on rooting, do it now, upgrade to a rooted Rom with TouchWiz (like Carbon), or go full 1337 and get a CynogenMod rom and run Kit Kat
5. Rooting your phone kills the warranty, but there are ways to revert back to stock. Depending on the insurance you have on the phone, they'll take in a broken rooted phone. However, if some phone component breaks, and you have no way to get it back stock, you are sort of SOL.
6. There is a huge market for used phones, and if you have yours rooted, you give a bit of added value to the phone. [Swappa](http://www.swappa.com) is probably the best place to go out and sell your phone.

TL;DR: Root now, install a rom you like, get KitKat if need be, sell on swappa.

Source: Rootin' since 2009. Owner of multiple Samsung phones.

Comment: If you already have a Knox bootloader you can root and install Knox Free ROMs happily. I've done it on S3 and S4 (i9505), but the Knox flag is set to 0x1 and currently this cannot be undone. Once the ROM is knox free there is no implication other than warranty. And even in that case Samsung have said in some cases that Knox flag isn't relevant to the warranty that rooting is. It's a grey area right now. There are root methods for Note 3 that don't trip knox but ANY custom kernel/bootloader/ROM will then trip it immediately. (Also I got knox in 4.2.2 in a patch, so check if you have it already)

Comment: Sorry to double comment, my point was that if you don't have knox I'd root first as Zlatty said above, if you already have it maybe read a bit on Knox before you root, factoring in your attitude to risk and what you want from the device.

Comment: Anyone know if downgrading phones with KNOX pre-installed lets you circumvent it?  https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65939/remove-knox-from-a-pre-installed-samsung-galaxy-note-ii