# Remove KNOX from a pre-installed Samsung Galaxy Note II

Tags: rom-flashing, device-firmware, samsung-galaxy-note-2

How should one remove KNOX from a pre-installed Samsung Galaxy Note II or similar?

As I understand it, [Samsung's official instructions](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/howtoguide/N0000005/13093/159642) for removing KNOX do not even remove the KNOX installer, but merely turn the KNOX installation off.

I'm curious about [this approach](http://www.s4miniarchive.com/2013/12/how-to-remove-knox-bootloader-from-new.html) to removing KNOX from Samsung phones.  As I understand it, removing the `aboot.mbn` and `sb*.mbn` files simply prevents them from being installed.  I doubt this helps if your device already has KNOX installed.

Could I first downgrade my GT 7100 to a pre-KNOX firmware?  And then flash a new firmware with the KNOX bootloader removed?  Or could I simply substitute the `aboot.mbn` and `sb*.mbn` files from a previous Samsung firmware?

Also, how could I actually find an old firmware for the Galaxy Note II?  I must presumably identify a firmware that's suitable for the hardware somehow?

Also, I'm using [heimdall](http://galaxynote2root.com/galaxy-note-2-root/how-to-root-galaxy-note-2-on-mac-osx/) under Mac OS X rather than Odin under Windows, so maybe I could just flash the ext4 `.img` file directly?  Is this a problem?  Is Odin required to avoid setting some warranty void bit or osmething?

Now my current firmware is N7100XXUEMJ9, which I've managed to download, appears Russian.  The most similar firmware available on Samsung's site is N7100XXUENC3.  It does not contain the `aboot.mbn` and `sb*.mbn` files.  Instead N7100XXUENC3 has `sboot.bin tz.img boot.img recovery.img system.img modem.bin cache.img hidden.img`.  I presume I could just flash the `system.img` from that without replacing the boot stuff?

Comment: Is this related to what safestrap does?  http://galaxynote3root.com/galaxy-note-3-tutorials/how-to-install-custom-rom-using-safestrap-on-galaxy-note-3/

Answer (score 1):

Root your note 2
Install titanium backup
Either uninstal or freeze Knox.apk and all associated processes through titanium backup.
As AWLAYS, make a complete backup before any changes.

Comment: That'll remove the user-space app, but not the KNOX bootloader or any other parts of the KNOX infrastructure.